# How to type with flowjs a Match component from reach router

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype, reach-router

The type definition is :

```
declare export class Match<Params> extends React$Component<{|
  path: string,
  children: (props: {|
    match: null | ({ uri: string, path: string } & Params),
    location: typeof location,
    navigate: NavigateFn,
  |}) => React$Node,
|}> {}
```

using Match like this :

```
<Match path="/agents/:id">
   {({ match, navigate }) => ( [...] )
</Match>
```

here `match` is consider as `null` by flow

if I try something like

```
class MatchAgent extends Match<{id: string}> {}
```

flow works great, but react crashes cannot call Class as function.

```
const MatchAgent: Match<{id:string}> = Match;
```

this works with react, but not with flow :'(

Is someone know how we can type this with flowjs ?
Thank you

EDIT: Here is my workaround

```
  const MatchAgent = new Match<{ id: string }>({
    path: '/agents/:id',
    children: ({ match, navigate }) => ([...]),
  });
```

Comment: "...react crashes cannot call Class as function." I think you should expand on this part a little bit. What's the stack trace here?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want `match` to be non-`null`. Unfortunately, according to the Flow type definition, `match` can be `null` or an object of the shape `{ uri: string, path: string } & Params`. To get Flow to stop complaining about `match` being `null`, you'll want to refine `match` by checking if it's `null`. For example,

```
import React from 'react';

declare export class Match<Params> extends React$Component<{|
  path: string,
  children: (props: {|
    match: null | ({ uri: string, path: string } & Params),
    location: any, // since location isn't defined in Try Flow
    navigate: any, // since NavigateFn isn't defined in Try Flow
  |}) => React$Node,
|}> {}

function App() {
  return (
    <Match path="/agents/:id">
      {({ match, navigate }) => {
        if (match === null) {
          return null; // or whatever you want when it doesn't match
        }

        return match.id;
      }}
    </Match>
  );
}
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocgEyTQBsUi4kAPSWOelAZ27gFkUMNAAsAPAAVGKENwB8zFjCQA7Kn2ToYAEgDCuSCtUwxAbwA+5OHDBCRALjjcYUYCoDmAGiucRwOlREKo4AFGA4YNyOFj7WIEKijioArnR0cOZwIaZwya6Ozq4enjZ2BS5u7nAAvnAAZHBSUDLcAJTe1tZ0EGhCwBDBcCgqAJ4lAPTjTm5oSHDdvTD9KnDA3Cr48DSYbkhUqysAKlAjcABi3QDusXAqKABuwO5CSI7DY3CT0yqzcAByDyeLzOKzWGy2SB2Rn2bjgx1OFwg12s5mqrTgAF4FJoMNo-hAaN5UQpTNVKJhkj8lgM4ABBMBgELo0w+IgwPIrELkACQYkEwhEpRgIgxACJxih3MZuON7MAqKK5DdrKZsnB4gKSndHs9lDV0Vi4CzOibVpgshrRJiMRjbqk6Mzlaa2Ry7WlSJ8ptA4JcRC97kgoHARhBkj7hvBfapVlsIEh1pt1QkRE7rGTU3AXVAVpaRAA6eUUU01MkmsTjfmiJXWVoUapAA)

Alternatively, if you have control of the Flow type definition (and implementation) for `Match`, you can remove `null` from the union type, `match: { uri: string, path: string } & Params`.